# Create view with the clause "option" included

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

I’m trying to create a view with the following sql

```
   create view v_month_days
   as
   with C(TheDate) as
   (
      select CAST('01/01/2014' AS DATETIME)
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, C.TheDate)
      from C
      where C.TheDate < CONVERT(VARCHAR (8), (DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, -1)),112)
   )
   select
     cast(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, C.TheDate), 0) as date) as Month,
     count(*) as DayCount
   from C
   group by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, C.TheDate), 0)
   option (maxrecursion 0);
```

But im receiving the following message:

> “Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure v_month_days, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'option'”

What other options I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the View first without the `Option` statement.

```
create view v_month_days
    as
    with C(TheDate) as
    (
      select CAST('01/01/2014' AS DATETIME)
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, C.TheDate)
      from C
      where C.TheDate < CONVERT(VARCHAR (8), (DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, -1)),112)
      )
     select cast(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, C.TheDate), 0) as date) as Month,
   count(*) as DayCount
   from C
    group by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, C.TheDate), 0)
```

Then when you select from the view, use the `Option` statement.

```
Select Month, DayCount From v_month_days
Option (maxrecursion 0);
```